# How to fix my encoding error in JamspellServer?

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, encoding

I deploy JamSpell-server with `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

EXPOSE 8080

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install wget tar cmake gcc make g++ locales -y
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app && \
    cd /opt/app && \
    wget https://github.com/bakwc/JamSpell/archive/master.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxf master.tar.gz

RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    sed -i -e 's/# ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8/ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen
ENV LANG ru_RU.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE ru_RU:ru  
ENV LC_ALL ru_RU.UTF-8 

WORKDIR /opt/app/JamSpell-master/build
RUN cmake .. && make

CMD ./web_server/web_server model.bin 0.0.0.0 8080
```

When I do request with `curl`, all good:

```json
❯ curl "https://myserver/candidates?text=лушчий"
{
    "results": [
        {
            "candidates": [
                "лучший",
                "лушчий"
            ],
            "len": 6,
            "pos_from": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I do request with browser, httpie or python.requests, encoding is wrong:

```json
{
    "results": [
        {
            "candidates": [
                "Ð»ÑÑÑÐ¸Ð¹",
                "Ð»ÑÑÑÐ¸Ð¹"
            ],
            "len": 6,
            "pos_from": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

How curl do it and how can I fix it?

Comment: UPD: if I add `| iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8` to httpie request, whe answer will be readable. But how can I do it in python?

Comment: ```❯ enca file.txt -L ru
Universal transformation format 8 bits; UTF-8
  Doubly-encoded to UTF-8 from ISO-8859-5  
```  
```❯ cat file.txt
Ð»ÑÑÑÐ¸Ð¹```